# How to position image dynamically in a specific order using css while changing the resolution?

Tags: html, css, image, position, line-breaks

I'm trying to learn css.

I've written this very simple code which displays 8 pictures in 2 rows, each row containing 4 pics. I'm intending to have this senario for wide resolutions.(picture below)
[4pics X 2rows -> OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtszV.png)

For smaller resolution widths I want only 2 pictures be in a row, therefore we have 4 rows of 2 pictures.(picture below)
[4pics X 4rows -> OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t4A3.png)

My problem is that when I change resolution to certain pixels, 1 picture moves to the next line while 3 others still remain for a row and I dont want this to happen.(picture below)
[(3+1)pics X 2rows -> **wrong scenario**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwk83.png)

I know I can handle it by using additional divs and `@media` tag `display:block/inline`, but I was wondering how can Ijust manage to handle it with css and not with adding any other element to html?

```css
body {}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 14vh;
}

.body-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.image-section img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="image-section">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-section">

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single mediaquerie should be enough :

idea:

```css
@media (max-width:868px) {
  .body-content .image-section {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

body {}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 14vh;
}

.body-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.image-section img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="image-section">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-section">

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />

      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use div to wrap each img like this

```css
body {}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 14vh;
}

.body-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .image-wrapper {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoOD-0XtKzjUAhidwtJKrcm9pm0VpNSETZ9g&usqp=CAU" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2020/articles/2020-10-16-11-04/-1602842658520.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justicechan/jw29z0eg/7/)

Or you can use displayinlineblock to make sure img

[Fiddle second approach](https://jsfiddle.net/justicechan/pg1oae2v/2/)

Comment: you can use the snippet button <> to create your live démo in your answer ;)